# What's immediate superset?

Tags: algorithms, association-rules

What's immediate superset?

Why is it called immediate?

They appear in the context of Apriori algorithm. Particularly the one enhanced with hashing.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please consider accepting to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

*Immediate* often occurs simply to say that there are perhaps many supersets, e.g. when we have a tree like structure. There is also for example, the converse, an *immediate subset*.

---

#### Example

Set **A** has a superset **B**, and that superset has its own superset **C**. In this case, **A** must also be contained within **C**, but the set **B** lies within that realm and so is the immedaite superset of **A**.

Perhaps it is best visualised with a Venn diagram, where **B** is the immediate superset of **A** and equally the immediate subset of **C**:

[image]

---

There is some discussion [here on Cross-Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/77465/maximal-closed-frequent-answer-included) too, where the selected answer shows some further usage of the term (albeit in a slightly different context). Have a look at [this source for some usage of the term](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~jin/DM08/FIM.pdf), which leads you to my understanding.

Comment: And it's specifically called immediate, rather than intermediate? Or does it always refer to the "next" or "previous", if there are more sets between?

Comment: At this point I personally would be just considering the linguistic connotation of the situation. Immediate means 'next to' and intermediate would mean 'between'. For example, if set D was the immediate superset of C, there would be several intermediate sets between e.g. A and D... Namely sets B and C. Does that help?

Comment: The use of the term immediate still seems a bit odd. It could mean e.g. the superset that contains "fewest additional sets".

Comment: I guess it could mean a great many things, depending on the context. Your suggestion seems to be a generalisation of my concret example. I would suggest to explain it very well whenever you use it yourself to save people this confusion!